# Aarray.map return value does not makes sense

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function copyArrayAndManipulate(array, instructions) {
  return array.map(function (element, index, arr) {
    return arr.push(instructions(element));
  });
}
function multiplyBy2(input) {
 return input * 2;
}
var result = copyArrayAndManipulate([1, 2, 3], multiplyBy2);
console.log(result)
```

I do not know why result equals to [4,5,6], i debugged it but i can't see the value 5 even while debugging.
Just trying to understand how this [4,5,6] array came from, not asking for some solution.

Comment: What is the result you are expecting?

Comment: multiplyBy2 doesn't return its calculation

Comment: sorry i tried with return*2 too result is still [4,5,6]. I did not understand where this 5 came from.

Comment: Why are you trying to both change the array you are passing and return a new array? Decide which one you want. I advise just returning a new array, in which case you can just return `instructions(element)`, no need for arr.push.

Comment: I already solved the issue here but trying to understand how result equals to [4,5,6]

Comment: `.push()` returns the new length of the array after the element has been pushed to your array, so. after the first push you get 4, then after the next you get 5 and lastly 6

Comment: Yes @NickParsons is right. You wrote return in front of `arr.push` which returns the current length of `arr`, So when you push `1*2` into an array it becomes `[1, 2, 3, 2]` which has length `4`, next time its `2*2 =4` results in `[1, 2, 3, 2, 4]` which has length `5`, then Its 3*4 results in `[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]` which has length `6`. So finally you got the result from map return `[4, 5, 6]`

Comment: @NickParsons thank you. That was the answer i looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`map` method will return you a new array. So you should not push to `arr` inside `map` method. You already get multiplied array

```
  function copyArrayAndManipulate(array, instructions) {
    return array.map(function (element, index, arr) {
      return instructions(element); // you should not push
    });
  }
  function multiplyBy2(input) {
    return input * 2;
  }
  var result = copyArrayAndManipulate([1, 2, 3], multiplyBy2);
```

Comment: I know but just trying to understand where [4,5,6] came from.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically rewriting `map` using `map`. `map` already does what you call `copyArrayAndManipulate`, so it seems like a useless wrap around a function that already exists. If you want your code to work, you simply need to remove `arr.push` and just return `instructions(element)` within the `map` function. The `map` function will return a new "copy" of the array and "manipulate" the array with the function you give it, passing you the each "element".